# Excel vba search in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ms-access, search

I need search in array

```
Sub f()
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Worksheets("QQ").Range("D:F")

    Dim searchTerm As String
    searchTerm = "927614*"

    'Check if a value exists in the Array
    If UBound(Filter(myArray, searchTerm)) >= 0 And searchTerm <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Your string match value from F column is " & myArray(Application.Match(searchTerm, myArray, False),3)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Search Term could NOT be located in the Array")
    End If
End Sub
```

But I get error Type mismatch. So how to lookup value with * in array?

Comment: You create a BIDIMENSIONAL array, Filter accept only ONE-DIMENSIONAL array. If you want to search one value you can use somethink like : Worksheets("QQ").Range("D:F").find ("927614*", lookin:=xlValues).row Eventually FindNext ...

Comment: but find is very slow as i need search 10000 searchterm values

Comment: onedimensional array also give an error

Comment: How you made the onedimensional array ? You can also use a VLOOKUP for every columns (3) and after read that in VBA or the Answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array and use `Like`.

Untested code:

```
Dim matchFound As Boolean
matchFound = False
For i = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(myArray, 2)
        If myArray(i, j) Like searchTerm Then
            MsgBox "Found match at (" & i & "," & j & ") : " & myArray(i, j)
            matchFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If matchFound Then Exit For
Next i
If Not matchFound Then MsgBox "No match found."
```